# Live site is an ubuntu, setting up wamp on local machine var/www not resolved

Tags: php, ubuntu, wamp, wampserver

I have a live site that is set up using `ubuntu`. All my files include a bunch of classes and they are all referenced at var/www/classes/class_name. My file structure is a lot different being on a wamp server.

I don't want to have to go through all my files and change the location to match that of the windows machine.

Is there an easy way to make my wamp server look in a windows directory structure when my php file says to look in var/www?

Comment: have you tried lamp or xampp ?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to have to go through all my files and change the location to match that of the windows machine.

You should be using relative paths anyway so that this isn't a problem.  I strongly suggest going back and fixing your paths so that you can move your code to wherever it needs to be.

> I have a live site that is set up using ubuntu.

You should be running your development code in an environment similar to where it will run in production.  I suggest using a tool like [Vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html) to manage a virtual machine for you that runs Ubuntu and whatever web server you run in production.  When you do this, you can also map directories over in any way you like.  (You should still solve your path problem though.)